# How can I send a success status to browser from nodejs/express?

Tags: forms, node.js, post, express

I've written the following piece of code in my nodeJS/Expressjs server:

```
app.post('/settings', function(req, res){
    var myData = {
        a: req.param('a')
        ,b: req.param('b')
        ,c: req.param('c')
        ,d: req.param('d')
    }

    var outputFilename = 'config.json';

    fs.writeFile(outputFilename, JSON.stringify(myData, null, 4), function(err) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Config file as been overwriten");
        }
    }); 
});
```

This allows me to get the submitted form data and write it to a JSON file.

This works perfectly. But the client remains in some kind of posting state and eventually times out. So I need to send some kind of success state or success header back to the client.

How should I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 171, accepted):

**Express Update 2015:**

Use this instead:

```
res.sendStatus(200)
```

This has been deprecated:

```
res.send(200)
```

Comment: Im getting ServerResponse has no method sendStatus

Comment: Are you sure you have Express installed and it is Express v4?

Comment: Yes! add the date to the answers. So many obsolete answers out there. Especially for rapidly changing stacks. We should be good for at least a couple of months :)

Comment: The sendStatus doesn't seem to work for me (version 4.0.0)

Comment: .sendStatus() is documented at http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus . I've added the link to the answer too.

Comment: Express 5 no longer supports the signature res.send(status).Instead, use this res.sendStatus(statusCode).

Answer (score 32):

Just wanted to add, that you can send json via the `res.json()` helper.

```
res.json({ok:true}); // status 200 is default
```

```
res.json(500, {error:"internal server error"}); // status 500
```

Update 2015:

`res.json(status, obj)` has been deprecated in favor of `res.status(status).json(obj)`

```
res.status(500).json({error: "Internal server error"});
```

Answer (score 13):

In express 4 you should do:

```
res.status(200).json({status:"ok"})
```

instead of the deprecated:

```
res.json(200,{status:"ok"})
```

Answer (score 12):

Jup, you need to send an answer back, the simplest would be

```
res.send(200);
```

Inside the callback handler of `writeFile`.

The 200 is a HTTP status code, so you could even vary that in case of failure:

```
if (err) {
    res.send(500);
} else {
    res.send(200);
}
```

Comment: yup that's exactly what's missing!