# Implementing Slack slash command delayed responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, slack-api

I built a Slack slash command that communicates with a custom Node API and POSTS acronym data in some way, shape, or form. It either gets the meaning of an acronym or adds/removes a new acronym to a Mongo database.

The command works pretty well so far, but Slack occasionally returns a timeout error because it expects a response within 3 seconds. As a result, I'm trying to implement delayed responses. **I'm not sure that I am implementing delayed responses properly for my Slack slash command & Node API.**

[This resource on Slack slash commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) has information on delayed responses. The idea is that I want to send a 200 response immediately to let the Slack user know that their request has been processed. Then I want to send a delayed response to `slackReq.response_url` that isn't constrained by the 3-second time limit.

**The Code**

```
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let request = require('request');

let slackHelper = require('../helpers/slack');

// ====================
// Slack Request Body
// ====================

// {
//   "token":"~",
//   "team_id":"~"
//   "team_domain":"~",
//   "channel_id":"~",
//   "channel_name":"~",
//   "user_id":"~",
//   "user_name":"~",
//   "command":"~",
//   "text":"~",
//   "response_url":"~"
// }

exports.handle = (req, res) => {
  let slackReq = req.body;
  let token = slackReq.token;
  let teamId = slackReq.team_id;

  if (!token || !teamId || !slackHelper.match(token, teamId)) {
    // Handle an improper Slack request 
    res.json({
      response_type: 'ephemeral',
      text: 'Incorrect request'
    });
  } else {
    // Handle a valid Slack request
    slackHelper.handleReq(slackReq, (err, slackRes) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          response_type: 'ephemeral',
          text: 'There was an error'
        });
      } else {
        // NOT WORKING - Immediately send a successful response
        res.json({
          response_type: 'ephemeral',
          text: 'Got it! Processing your acronym request...'
        })

        let options = {
          method: 'POST',
          uri: slackReq.response_url,
          body: slackRes,
          json: true
        };

        // Send a delayed response with the actual acronym data
        request(options, err => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

**What's Happening Right Now**

Say I want to find the meaning of acronym NBA. I go on Slack and shoot out the following:

`/acronym NBA`

I then hit the 3-second timeout error - `Darn – that slash command didn't work (error message: Timeout was reached). Manage the command at slash-command`.

I send a request a few more times (2 to 4 times), and then the API finally returns, all at once:

`Got it! Processing your acronym request...`

`NBA means "National Basketball Association".`

**What I Want to Happen**

I go on Slack and shoot out the following:

`/acronym NBA`

I immediately get the following:

`Got it! Processing your acronym request...`

Then, outside of the 3-second window, I get the following:

`NBA means "National Basketball Association".`

I never hit a timeout error.

**Conclusion**

What am I doing wrong here? For some reason, that `res.json()` with the processing message isn't immediately being sent back. What can I do to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit 1**

I tried to replace the `res.json()` call with `res.sendStatus(200).json()`, but unfortunately, that only returned an 'OK' without actually processing the request.

I subsequently tried `res.status(200).send({..stuff..})` but that resulted in the same problem I was having before.

I think `res.json()` sends a 200 automatically anyway, but its just not responding fast enough for some reason.

**Solution**

I eventually figured this one out. I was implementing the delayed responses right all along.

Since I'm using the free plan for Heroku, the dyno that's hosting my app would go down after 30 minutes of inactivity. When the app went down, the first few requests would time out on Slack before properly responding to a request.

The solution to this is either 1) upgrade to a new plan that keeps the dyno active at all times, or 2) ping the app with a simple get request every 15 or so minutes, like so:

```
const intervalMins = 15; 

setInterval(() => {
  http.get("<insert app url here>");
  console.log('Ping!');
}, intervalMin * 60000)
```

I decided to go with the latter option. I don't run into the issue of the dyno sleeping anymore. I'd check [this article](https://quickleft.com/blog/6-easy-ways-to-prevent-your-heroku-node-app-from-sleeping/) for more details.

Comment: Have you tried this? `res.sendStatus(200);`. Should work according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397691/how-can-i-send-a-success-status-to-browser-from-nodejs-express) answer.

Comment: I'll try it out now. Replicating the problem requires not using the API for a while (interestingly...), so I'll add another comment based on the success and failure, then update the post with the code I tried.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken unfortunately that didn't work, but thank you for the suggestion. See Edit 1 above.